# 2 dimensional character array

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define rsize 3
#define csize 3

int
main()
{
    char tictac[rsize][csize];
    int a, b;

    printf("WELCOME TO TIC TAC TOE \n");

    for(a = 0; a < rsize; a++)
    {
        for(b = 0; b < csize; b++)
        {
            printf("Enter X or O: ");
            scanf(" %c", &tictac[a][b]);
        }
    }
    for(a = 0; a < rsize; a++)
    {
        if (tictac[a][0] == tictac[a][1] && tictac[a][1] == tictac[a][2]);
        {
            printf("Row %d has all %c's \n", a, tictac[a][0]);
        }
        if (tictac[0][a] == tictac[1][a] && tictac[1][a] == tictac[2][a]);
        {
            printf("Column %d has all %c's \n", a, tictac[0][a]);
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

It's supposed to be a 3x3 tictac toe game but it doesn't seem to be working.  The problem is the `if statement` I'm not sure why it doesn't work.  Come someone help me out and point out my problem?

Comment: It compiles very well on my system(Fedora64bit).Only problem is when i copied the code. There is a trailling semicolons at the end of file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have extra semicolons in the middle of the `if` statements that cause them to be empty.  So your code is effectively

```
if (...) {
   /* do nothing */
}
{
    printf(...
}
```

and the printfs are always executed.  Get rid of the ';' between the ')' and the '{'

Comment: I can't believe I did that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After IF( condition), you have placed a semicolon(;).
Remove that.